# If $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$, what does $\{\{a\}\}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the significance of curly brackets in set theory.

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$.

I understand $A$ is a set that includes the objects $a,b,c,d$.  However, what does $\{\{a\}\}$ mean?  Why use two curly brackets on either side instead of just $\{a\}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How does $\{a\}$ differ from $\{\{a\}\}$? Well, Omnomnomnom and vadim123 have pointed out the key differences, but perhaps a small elaboration will help.

Is $a\in\{a\}$? Yes. Is $a\in\{\{a\}\}$? Well, $a\neq\{a\}$ so the answer is a resounding no. Ah, but do you know what it means for a set to be a subset of another set? If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then this is often denoted by $A\subseteq B$ and may be thought of as "if $x$ is $A$, then $x$ is in $B$"; symbolically, $A\subseteq B$ may be represented as $x\in A\to x\in B$. This illustrates some key points:

- $a\in \{a\}$
- $\{a\}\in\{\{a\}\}$
- $\color{blue}{\{a\}\subseteq \{a\}}$
- $\color{blue}{\{a\}\not\in\{a\}}$

Pay special attention to the last two points highlighted in blue.

Comment: Also of note is that in ZFC a can not possibly even be possibly be {a}.

Answer (score 6):

$\{\{a\}\}$ means the set containing the set containing $a$.

Think of sets like bags.  $a$ is an apple.  $\{a\}$ is an apple in a bag.  $\{\{a\}\}$ is an apple in a bag, that is in another bag.

Answer (score 4):

The set $\{\{a\}\}$ is the set whose only object is the set $\{a\}$.  $\{a\}$, in turn, is a set whose only object is $a$.

It might help to consider the set 
$$
\{a,\{a\},\{b\}\}
$$
whose objects are $a$, the set $\{a\}$, and the set $\{b\}$.  Note that this set is quite different from $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Ah, ok gotcha.  So then in that case, if A = {a,b,c,d}, then {{a}} would not be a subset of P(A), correct?

Comment: @OmarN $\{\{a\}\}$ is a subset of $P(A)$ because each of its elements is an element of $P(A)$ (that is, each element is a subset of $A$). Indeed the only element $\{a\}$ is a subset of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ because each element of the former(there is only $a$) is an element of the latter.

Comment: Actually, $\{\{a\}\}$ *would* be a subset of $P(A)$ since its only element is also an element of $P(A)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for the comment; I had misread the question

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Would it also follow to say that $\emptyset$ is not a subset of P(A), but {$\emptyset$} is a subset of P(A)?

Comment: @OmarN I imagine [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167345/is-an-empty-set-equal-to-another-empty-set/1167352#1167352), which gives *numerous* properties concerning what $\emptyset$ is an element and/or subset of, would be quite useful to you.

Comment: Thank you!  That does help.  Looks like my guess is correct.

Comment: Actually, $\emptyset$ is a subset of *every* set.  It so happens that both $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are subsets of $P(A)$

Answer (score 2):

If $\{a\}$ is the set whose only element is $a$; denote that set by $x$, then $\{x\}$ is the set whose unique element is $x$, so its unique element is $\{a\}$, which in other words mean that it is the set $\{\{a\}\}$.